# show celle in table view with timestamp swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView showing 10,30 or 50 items.
I would like to change this. I would like it to load and show 10 every the first time I access the controller and then after reaching the 10 cell make me a reload make a request to the history by putting a range field in the body: 'from-to', both timestamps with from = midnight of 7 days before the last transaction and to = one second before the last transaction.

currently I have a button that by pressing you can choose 10,30 or 50 and shows the cells.

```
    class TransactionListViewController : UIViewController {
    
    var operationTransactionListRunning : Bool
    
    let choices : [String] = ["Ultimi 10 movimenti","Ultimi 30 movimenti","Ultimi 50 movimenti"]
    let choicess : [Int] = [10, 30, 50]
    let TRANSACTION_CELL_HEIGHT: CGFloat = 110
    fileprivate let reuId_transaction_cell = "TransactionCell"
    var transactions: [Transaction]?
    var userData: UserData?
    lazy var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var transactionsTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var limitView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var limitLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var noTransactionsLabel: UILabel!
    
    var spinner : LoadingView?
    var limitValue :Int = 0
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        operationTransactionListRunning = false
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        limitLabel.tag = 0
        limitLabel.text = choices[limitLabel.tag]
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector(limitViewClicked))
        limitView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        
        spinner = LoadingView(frame: view.frame)
        spinner?.view = view
        setTableView()
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        (navigationController as? TPCustomNavigationViewController)?.backButtonIsHidden(false)
        if AppDelegate.sharedInstance().stellarError ?? false {
            AppDelegate.sharedInstance().stellarError = false
            spinner?.startSpinner()
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+5, execute: {
                self.makeGetHistory(false, true)
            })
        }
        else {
            makeGetHistory(false, true)
        }
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        limitLabel.tag = 0
        limitLabel.text = choices[limitLabel.tag]
    }

    
    @objc func limitViewClicked(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Lista movimenti", message: "Scegli quanti movimenti mostrare", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: choices[0], style: .default, handler: { (action :UIAlertAction) in
            if self.limitLabel.tag != 0 {
                self.limitLabel.tag = 0
                self.limitLabel.text = self.choices[0]
                self.makeGetHistory(false, true)
            }
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: choices[1], style: .default, handler: { (action :UIAlertAction) in
            if self.limitLabel.tag != 1 {
                self.limitLabel.tag = 1
                self.limitLabel.text = self.choices[1]
                self.makeGetHistory(false, true)
            }
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: choices[2], style: .default, handler: { (action :UIAlertAction) in
            if self.limitLabel.tag != 2 {
                self.limitLabel.tag = 2
                self.limitLabel.text = self.choices[2]
                self.makeGetHistory(false, true)
            }
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Annulla", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        alert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
    
    func setTableView(){
        //refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: .valueChanged)
        transactionsTableView.addSubview(refreshControl) 
        transactionsTableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 0
        transactionsTableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 0
        transactionsTableView.register(UINib(nibName: reuId_transaction_cell, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: reuId_transaction_cell)
        transactionsTableView.separatorStyle = .none
        transactionsTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        transactionsTableView.estimatedRowHeight = TRANSACTION_CELL_HEIGHT
        transactionsTableView.allowsSelection = true
        transactionsTableView.delegate = self
        transactionsTableView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    @objc func refresh() {
        makeGetHistory(true, true)
        //refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
    
    func makeGetHistory(_ isRefreshing: Bool, _ forceUpdate: Bool) {
        if operationTransactionListRunning {
            if isRefreshing {
                refreshControl.endRefreshing()
                self.transactionsTableView.contentOffset = CGPoint.zero
            }
            return
        }
        operationTransactionListRunning = true
        if !isRefreshing {
            spinner?.startSpinner()
        }
        TPContentManager.sharedInstance.transactions(choicess[limitLabel.tag], { ( transactions: Int?, error: NetworkError?) in
            self.operationTransactionListRunning = false
            if isRefreshing {
                self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
            }
            else{
                self.spinner?.stopSpinner()
            }
            if let eerror = error {
                if isRefreshing {
                    self.transactionsTableView.contentOffset = CGPoint.zero
                }
                var m = ERRM_general
                if let msg = eerror.message {
                    m = msg
                }
                print("error login" + m)
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: ERRT_general, message: m, preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:L_Ok, style: .default, handler: nil))
                
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            else{
                self.buildCells()
            }
        }, forceUpdate)
    }

    func getExpirationDate(_ hash: String){
        guard !operationTransactionListRunning else { return }
        operationTransactionListRunning = true
        spinner?.startSpinner()
        TPClientApi.sharedInstance.expirationDate(hash, {(result: Int?, data: [ExpirationDate]?, error: NetworkError?) in
            self.spinner?.stopSpinner()
            self.operationTransactionListRunning = false
            if let e = error {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: ERRT_general, message: e.message ?? ERRM_general, preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:L_Ok, style: .default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            else{
                if let data = data {
                    var s = String()
                    for d in data {
                        if let a = d.amount, let e = d.expirationDate {
                            s.append("\(a) - \(e)\n")
                        }
                    }
                    if s.count > 0 {
                        var ss = "Totale tickets spesi - Data scadenza\n"
                        s.popLast()
                        ss.append(s)
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: T_general, message: ss, preferredStyle: .alert)
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:L_Ok, style: .default, handler: nil))
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                    else {
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: ERRT_general, message: ERRM_general, preferredStyle: .alert)
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:L_Ok, style: .default, handler: nil))
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
    
    
    func buildCells(){
        guard let t = TPContentManager.sharedInstance.transactions
         else { return }
        transactions = t
        noTransactionsLabel.isHidden = t.count > 0
        userData = TPContentManager.sharedInstance.userData
        transactionsTableView.reloadData(with: .none)
            if t.count > 0 {
                transactionsTableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0), at: UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: true)
            }
    }
}

//MARK: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource

extension TransactionListViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellData: Transaction = self.transactions![indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuId_transaction_cell, for: indexPath) as! TransactionCell
//        if(cellData.type == 0){
//            cell.restaurantNameLabel.text = "Ristorante"
//        }
//        else {
//            cell.restaurantNameLabel.text = cellData.shopName ?? cellData.name
//        }
        //cell.initUI()
        cell.restaurantNameLabel.text = cellData.getNameOf(true)//"\(cellData.getNameOf(true)) \(indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ? "aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa":"")"
        cell.dateLabel.text = cellData.date?.getAsDateString()
        cell.timeLabel.text = cellData.date?.getAsTimeString()
        cell.ticketNumberViewBackgroundColor = indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ? UIColor.white : UIColor.init("#eeeeee")
        switch cellData.type {
            case 0, 2:
                cell.redImageView.isHidden = false
                cell.greenImageView.isHidden = true
                cell.priceLabel.textColor = .customRedColor
                cell.priceLabel.text = "- "+(cellData.amount).italianRappresentation() + " €"
            case 1:
                cell.redImageView.isHidden = true
                cell.greenImageView.isHidden = false
                cell.priceLabel.textColor = .customGreenColor
                cell.greenImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "triangle_cashout")
                cell.priceLabel.text = cellData.amount.italianRappresentation() + " €"
            case 3:
                cell.redImageView.isHidden = true
                cell.greenImageView.isHidden = false
                cell.priceLabel.textColor = .primaryColor
                cell.greenImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "triangle_yellow")
                cell.priceLabel.text = cellData.amount.italianRappresentation() + " €"
            default:
                break
            }
        if userData?.isContinue ?? false {
            cell.ticketNumberLabel.superview?.alpha = 0
        }
        else {
            cell.ticketNumberLabel.text = String(cellData.tickets)
        }
            //cell.priceLabel.text = "€ " + (cellData.tickets * userData!.ticket_value).italianRappresentation()
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        //cell.labelValue.text = cellData.value
        //cell.labelSubValue.text = cellData.subValue
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        transactions?.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard !(userData?.isContinue ?? true) else {
            return
        }
        let cellData = self.transactions![indexPath.row]
        guard cellData.type == 0, let hash = cellData.hash else {return}
        self.getExpirationDate(hash)
    }
```

[actually view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQeDy.jpg)

Comment: I would recommend you approach this strictly through your data model and not worry about the table view, just let the table view load what the data model will give it.  So, for example, instead of passing the entire transactions array, you could use the filter(_:) method to return an array based on the date filters you want to use, and then just modify the date filter as needed.  Or, better yet, replace the array with an object that supports sorting/filtering on a property, something like a Realm object.

Comment: @SuperTully ok, for it's another management isn't it? or rather, now from the code I say to reload when I press the button, I should set it to reload when the 10 cell is scrolled the first time, reload and add the other transactions in the queue